# Scrolling window to zero to hide Mobile Safari browser chrome seems slower than Twitter's

Tags: javascript, iphone, scroll, mobile-safari

I'm using the following JS to scroll the window to position 0 to fool the browser into hiding its UI chrome.

```
if navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) or navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  if document.URL.indexOf("#") is -1
    window.addEventListener "load", ->
      setTimeout (->
        window.scrollTo 0, 1  if window.pageYOffset < 20
      ), 0
```

You can view the site at http://ssaen.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com on your iPhone or iPod touch. The scroll happens quickly but there is a big delay before the chrome goes away.

Compare this to http://mobile.twitter.com (you'll have to login to see the main UI), the chromes goes away almost immediately. Twitter's scripts are obscured so I can't see them.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the JS scripts at the bottom are blocking the page `load` event. You can try concatenate all the JS files into one and use `<script defer>`.

Refer to the [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/script-defer) for the `defer` attribute. Also do look at the [`async` attribute](http://caniuse.com/script-async) as well.

Comment: I've removed the scripts below. Didn't work. I suspect it's TypeKit and removed it but still didn't work. I removed Google web fonts, still didn't work! I wonder if it's just too much for the browser to render.

Comment: @AenTan I think the images might be blocking too.